# Unable to get user location in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get user location using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-) package but i m unable to get location without any error message. Code never passes the `await location.getLocation();` line.

I have tried flutter clean and down grading location package from 2.3.5 to 1.4.0 but that didn't help i did that because that version worked in the past but after upgrading flutter android studio and gradle to latest things don't work like before. I also tried to use geolocator package but faced exact same problem.

here is my code.

```
Future<LocationData> _getLocation() async {
Location location = new Location();
var currentLocation;
          try {
            currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
          } catch (e) {
            currentLocation = null;
          }
return currentLocation;
}
```

there is no error in console i am using vscode
here is flutter doctor output.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.5.4-hotfix.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.765], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.1 at C:\Users\kawak\sdk\flutter
    • Framework revision 09cbc34a0b (5 weeks ago), 2019-04-30 15:44:27 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\androidsdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\androidsdk
    • Java binary at: D:\android\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at D:\android
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Alhamdulillah found solution i was using beta channel moving to stable one was needed

Answer (score 4):

This is the method I use to get location. Hope it helps.

```
void _getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      await location.getLocation().then((onValue) {
              print(onValue.latitude.toString() + "," + onValue.longitude.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
       _handlePermissionDenied();
      }
    }
  }
```

You can also try geolocation but I have found that `location` plugin is faster than the `geolocation` plugin.

Comment: thanks but i tried geolocation but faced exact same problem how can both plogins have same problem at same time

Comment: I tried it too - and it doesn't work on my Android simulator. The getLocation never returns. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

You're using a catch without printing the error .. Remove it and you'll more than probably have a beautiful message telling you what the error is !

Comment: i have tried printing error but catch block doesn't run but thanks.

Comment: ^^; Did you try to manually autorise your app to access the localisation (in the android settings, to see if the problem is coming from there) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with flutter library : [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-)

```
var currentLocation = LocationData;

var location = new Location();

try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
    error = 'Permission denied';
  } 
  currentLocation = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to use location [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/location).

In the documentation of the plugin there is a suggestion to add some permissions:

- iOS: In Info.plist (ios/Runner) *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* and *NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* must be added. The latter is important if you are gonna listen constantly for location.
- Android: There is no necessity of add any permission because the plugin already does it internally. (if you are using flutter version 1.12+)

Now, in order to request location, we should always check manually Location Service status and Permission status:

```
Future<void> manageLocationPermission() async {
  LocationData locationData;
  final Location location = Location();
  bool serviceEnabled;
  PermissionStatus permissionGranted;

  serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return;
    }
  }

  permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
  if (permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
    permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    //TODO: do your logic to manage when user denies the permission
    if (permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      _buildMapLocatorDialog();
      return;
    }
  }
  locationData = await location.getLocation();
  //TODO: do your logic to manage when user grants the permission
  viewModel.onMapLocatorClick(locationData);
}
```

This function is called after the user clicks on the GPS icon to center/get current location, but according to your needs, you need to call it wherever you require it